# Creating power point presentation using iphone photos

Tags: iphone

I have iPhone 5S and I want to create a powerpoint presentation but want to keep on the original resolution of the photos I take from my iPhone.
How can I insert the photos from iPhone to my power point presentation AND keep on the quality of the photos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have inserted the pic in PowerPoint, use the Compress function where you can select the resolution, or keep the original.

[image: resolution]